# Pass 64-bit int as output to 32-bit inline asm

Tags: c++, c, gcc, inline-assembly

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t test_func(int n)
{
    return 9223372036854775805;
}


int main()
{
    uint64_t r = test_func(10);

    return 0;
}
```

converts to:

```
test_func(int):
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, -3
    mov edx, 2147483647
    pop ebp
    ret

main:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    and esp, -8
    sub esp, 24
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], 10
    call    test_func(int)
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+16], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+20], edx
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

You can see it uses 2 registers to store that 64-bit integer. However, in the C/C++ code, it is only ONE variable.

I tried to replicate this in inline-assembly but I had to do:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t test_func(int n)
{
    return 9223372036854775805;
}


int main()
{
    int32_t rlow = 0, rhigh = 0;

    asm(
        "push $10\n"
        "\tcall %P2"
        : "=a"(rlow), "=d"(rhigh)
    : "i"(&test_func) : "memory");

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
test_func(int):
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, -3
    mov edx, 2147483647
    pop ebp
    ret
main:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 0
    push $10
    call test_func(int)
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], edx
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Now you can see I had to manually place the lower and higher order bits into two separate integers. Then I perform shifting to make it into one 64-bit integer.

Is there a way to automatically get it to place into a single 64-bit integer without me having to supply it two 32-bit integers and then shifting the bits?

Comment: Looks like output from a 32-bit compiler. If you use a 64-bit compiler, it'll probably use 64-bit registers directly.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html Look under 386, letter 'A'. Yes, that's the first place you should have been looking at...

Comment: 32-bit code cannot use 64-bit registers. It has to be executable on 32-bit architectures. That's why it's called 32-bit code.

Comment: Also, there's no "C/C++".

Comment: I know there's no such thing as "C/C++". I put it there for "C OR C++" because the above code is both valid C and valid C++. Difference being the headers.. but anyone would notice that.

Comment: The above code is not valid C. Those headers don't exist in C; at least not under those names.

Comment: Hence why I said: **`Difference being the headers`**. `stdint.h` and `stdargs.h` instead of `cstdint` and `cstdargs` for C.

Comment: Nitpick: it isn't valid C++ either, cstdint might provide std::int64_t without ::int64_t. Including stdint.h instead would also make it valid C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `"A"` constraint, which binds a 64-bit value to the eax/edx register pair.  Something like:

```
uint64_t r;
asm("push $10\n"
    "\tcall %P1"
    : "=A"(r) : "i"(&test_func) : "memory");
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Please link to the official doc, since people seem to have a hard time finding it :-(

Comment: [Machine Constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) - search the page for "Intel 386"